# Why did Olaf specfically mention 4 humans?

Tags: frozen-ii

This is the line said by Olaf:

> Olaf: Water has memory. The water that makes up you and me, has passed through at least **four humans**, and, or animals, before us.

Why did Olaf specifically mention 4 humans?

Comment: I haven't seen Frozen 2, but I am disappointed to hear that they're trying to press Homeopathy pseudoscience onto kids.

Comment: @AaronLavers but you're OK with the talking snowman??

Comment: @AakashM I feel there's more validity in the science behind possessed demon snowmen than in homeopathy :P

Comment: @AaronLavers I’d rather say, it’s a good move to place Homeopathy were it belongs, a fairytale with a talking snowman.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I turned up this article from [2018](https://www.absolute-knowledge.com/the-water-you-drink-was-already-drunk-at-least-4-times/)

> considering safe assumptions, the water we drink has been drunk at least 4 times in the past. This number can increase up to 10 times in extreme cases. As dinosaurs ruled over the Earth a long time ago, it is a common perception that every glass of water we drink has actually gone through the guts of a dinosaur.

So it appears to be injected science knowledge and not an in-universe specific factoid.

Comment: Well, the source quote did say "four humans, and, or (sic) animals"

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- this is me failing at reading. I even added that "mangled" bit in as an edit as I thought I misread it the first time.